# Submit many forms to Spring Boot with single Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I have a page with many forms (this is a thymeleaf page and forms are created dynamically). This forms consists of String data and one file each.

I want to be able to collect all the data from all the forms and sent this to Spring controller.

I am able to send and receive single form with no problem but I cannot figure out how to do this with many forms.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="someId" class="someClass">
        <div th:each="someDiv, iterStat : ${someVar}"  >
            <form id="form" method="post" th:name="'form' + ${someVar.someVarId}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div th:id="${someVar.someVarId}" name="someName">
                        <input   type="text" th:value="${someVar.someText}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <center><label>radio button</label></center>
                    <input id="one"  type="radio" name="radioButton" value="0" th:checked="${someVar.radio} == 0"/>1
                    <input id="two"  type="radio" name="radioButton" value="1" th:checked="${someVar.radio} == 1"/>2
                <center><label>drop-down list</label></center>
                    <select id="dropList">
                        <option id="1" value="0" th:selected="${someVar.list} == 0">0</option>
                        <option id="2" value="1" th:selected="${someVar.list} == 1">1</option>
                        <option id="3" value="2" th:selected="${someVar.list} == 2">2</option>
                    </select>
                <input type="file" id="fileinput" />
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var  someName= $('div[name="someName"]');

var myForm = new FormData();
for(var i = 0; i < someName.length; i++) {

    myForm.append("var1", $(someName[i]).attr('id'));
    myForm.append("var2", $(someName[i]).find('input.form-control').val());
    myForm.append("var3", $(someName[i]).find('input[name=radioButton]:checked').val());
    myForm.append("var4", $(someName[i]).find('#dropList option:selected').val());
    myForm.append("file", $('#fileinput').prop('files')[0]);
}


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType : false,
    processData: false,
    url: "/url",
    data: myForm,
    success: function(response) {
       console.log("success");

    }
});
```

and the Spring Controller as below:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/url")
public ModelAndView update(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println(file);
}
```

In the controller I would like to receive all the information from forms in some kind of array which I could iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

Get all form elements

```
var formsAll = document.querySelectorAll('form');
```

Get the form data for each element

```
var formDataAll = formsAll.map(form => new FormData(form));
```

Pass the data to your ajax handler

```
$.ajax({
  data: formDataAll
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, however I got following error with your code:
`Uncaught TypeError: formsAll.map is not a function`

Comment: I got it working with `var formsAll = []; formsAll = document.querySelectorAll('form');` but I am unable to retrive this form on the controller side

Comment: Try sending it as the value of a key in an object: `data: {myData: new FormData()}`